# Java source vs. Android SDK differences?

Tags: android

If I look at the source code for `AudioManager`, there is:

```java
@SdkConstant(SdkConstantType.BROADCAST_INTENT_ACTION)
public static final String VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION = "android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION";
```

However, is not visible by Eclipse, even when you specify the minimum SDK level.

How can this happen?

Is this part of the API or not?

Thanks

Comment: a assume that AudioManager is a class and not project?!
Didn't find at: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/index.html

Answer (score 2):

You missed the part above, the @hide indicating it is not included in the SDK:

```
/**
 * @hide Broadcast intent when the volume for a particular stream type changes.
 * Includes the stream, the new volume and previous volumes
 *
 * @see #EXTRA_VOLUME_STREAM_TYPE
 * @see #EXTRA_VOLUME_STREAM_VALUE
 * @see #EXTRA_PREV_VOLUME_STREAM_VALUE
 */
```