# How to receive volume changed events for the voice (in-call) stream type?

Tags: android

I'm trying to register a broadcast receiver to handle the `VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION` event, only for the `volume_voice` stream type (which I empirically see to be index `0` in `Settings.System.VOLUME_SETTINGS`).

The label `EXTRA_VOLUME_STREAM_TYPE` is hidden, so I have used the explicit string `"android.media.EXTRA_VOLUME_STREAM_TYPE"` instead. It all worked fine on Android 2.3.4 (got value `0` for `volume_voice` as expected), but on 2.3.5 the value that this extra holds is `10`, which gives an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` on `Settings.System.VOLUME_SETTINGS`.
Moreover, I see that `volume_voice` is still index `0` in `Settings.System.VOLUME_SETTINGS`.

Is there a more robust way to handle `VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION` for `volume_voice` stream types?

**Edit** Or any other way to do what the title asks for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My temporary (and probably bad) workaround is to catch the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, and in the catch block to test the stream type to have value of `Settings.System.VOLUME_SETTINGS.length`.

This is the best I have so far. I don't know if it might catch other stream types as well, and also if it is going to work on other Android versions than 2.3.3-2.3.5.

Answer (score 10):

> I'm trying to register a broadcast receiver to handle the VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION event

[There is no `VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION` in the Android SDK.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764279/java-source-vs-android-sdk-differences)

> The label EXTRA_VOLUME_STREAM_TYPE is hidden, so I have used the explicit string "android.media.EXTRA_VOLUME_STREAM_TYPE" instead.

There is no `EXTRA_VOLUME_STREAM_TYPE` in the Android SDK.

> Is there a more robust way to handle VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION for volume_voice stream types?

There is no `VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION` in the Android SDK.

Whatever you are trying to do is undocumented, unsupported, may not work on any given version of Android (past/present/future), and may not work on any given device (since manufacturers can change anything that is not in the SDK). It will never be "robust", by definition.