# can i track volume increase and decrease when screen is locked?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, background-service

I found similar questions but they dont completely answer the question. I am trying to start an activity when the volume button is pressed in a certain order. The best lead I got was about using a broadcast receiver but I cannot figure out how exactly i am supposed to implement that.

Could anyone show me some example code for it or anything that would help me understand how to implement it?

```
public class RemoteControlReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent)intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
            Log.e("LOGGER","LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL");
            /*if (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY == event.getKeyCode()) {
                // Handle key press.

            }*/
        }
    }

}





 <receiver android:name=".RemoteControlReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only for Media Buttons(Volume up or down button will not work) :

Here you go. Read this tutorial from developer site itself. It will give you the idea.

Link : http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/volume-playback.html

On a high level,

1. Register a Broadcast receiver dynamically or through manifest. Google for the difference.
2. Write a broadcast receiver to do the operation when you get a callback on Volume key press.

Comment: I added the receiver through the manifest        <receiver android:name=".RemoteControlReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>          But it does not run the code in my onRecieve() method.

Comment: Cool. Have you implemented the solution?

Comment: I did but it does not detect the volume button presses while the app is running let alone when the app is in the paused

Comment: ive edited my initial question with the broadcast reciever and the manifest entry. could you please tell me why that Log is not showing up when i push the audio button

Comment: Sorry. It is only for media buttons and not for volume up and down. My apologies.

Comment: do you know if there is a action related to volume change?

Comment: Sadly, There is no broadcast intent for Volume up/down buttons.This might be a measure to avoid apps to mess up with Volume up/down button actions as they are vital for any phone. I found only [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234176/volume-change-listener-is-registermediabuttoneventreceiver-preferable-to-onkeyd) with some insights for your question.