# Android: How can I detect selfie-stick button click when my app is in background

Tags: java, android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

I am building an Android app, which detects the selfie-stick button click connected to the mobile audio jack.

I am able to capture the button click if the app is in the foreground, but not in the background.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
   switch (keyCode) {
       case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
           Toast.makeText(CustomPadActivity.this, "BUTTON clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           return true;
   }
   return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

I tried using the broadcast receiver with action `android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON` but it is not capturing the button click at all.

**Manifest:**

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And my **Receiver class:**

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "BUTTON clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

I read somewhere I need to play a piece of music if I want to capture the button click. The app is not an audio player. I don't want to play audio in the app.

I am just trying to capture the selfie-stick button click when my app is in the background.

Comment: even setting the intent-filter priority to 999 or any other number didn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

This is of course

> onKeyEvent only can be callbacks in the activity

Services simply do not receive KeyEvent callbacks.

Add intent to AndroidManifest in Activtiy

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
</intent-filter>
```

and add this in your Activity or it will not show on your lockscreen.

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
}
```

Comment: How "android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" intent-filter in Activity will actually help me to capture when the app is in the background?

Comment: I was wrong, it really should be in the receiver, you can do it in onReceive
if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON))
// do something

Comment: Done that already, didn't work, mentioned the same in my question too.

Comment: Have you tried registering BroadcastReceiver with Service? Then capture it with onReceive too. RegisterReceiver (myReceiver, new IntentFilter ("android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION"));

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/44040282/11732119

Comment: Hey, I tried with the link you have provided, It is kind of working partially. Whatever the priority I set, android OS is taking the first priority when I click the stick button, but if I click the button twice immediately, then my app is able to capture the second click.