# Android dispatchKeyEvent , onKeyDown callbacks not working with gesture volume control (Huawei mate 30 pro)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-support-library, huawei-developers

I have added dispatchKeyEvent and onKeyDown to detect volume change events inside activity which is working fine with devices having physical volume buttons. In the case of Huawei mate 30 pro above events are not firing as it doesn't have physical volume buttons but a gesture to control volume.
Any solution ??

```
 override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
    d(TAG, "signal onKeyDown $keyCode")
    when (keyCode) {
        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME -> {
            d(TAG, "signal onKeyDown KEYCODE_HOME")
            if (alertDialog != null && alertDialog?.isShowing == true) {
                releaseDataAndFinishActivity()
            }
           
            return false
        }
        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK -> {
            onBackPressed()
            return false
        }
        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN -> {
            updateVolumeOnKeyPress(false)
            return true
        }
        else -> return true
    }
}

override fun onKeyUp(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
        updateVolumeOnKeyPress(true)
        return true
    }
    return false
}

override fun dispatchKeyEvent(event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
    d(TAG, "signal dispatchKeyEvent $event")
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event)
}
```

Comment: hi@Muhammad Ali, may i ask which gesture you are using ?

Comment: hi@Muhammad Ali, According to the team, Huawei P40 Pro is a physical button, not a virtual button.  Could you pls reconfirm the model of the phone?

Comment: @shirley sorry it's Huawei mate 30 pro, not p40.

Answer (score 0):

About How to Detect Volume Change events in Activity on the Mate30 Pro, You can achieve this by listening to the `android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION` broadcast.

Comment: I cannot use this action in prod because it's not working for all devices. Secondly, it is not part of SDK and it might be removed in the future. 

**See**  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4764881/15791414)

Comment: According to the team, Currently Android does not define such hardware. This is provided by Huawei and does not have standard interfaces. If you don't want to use it, there may hava no other way. 